# Send PDF download link by email Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

In fact in my detail page of a publication I have a download button.
when we click on "donwload" a popup opens in which we enter the email of the receiving user and a pdf link will be sent to this email.
I managed to display the popup but I could not find a solution to send the PDF download link. I do not know how to retrieve this link knowing that when adding a publication I have a file that will be saved in the database as a file attribute containing the file name with the extension pdf.
thank you for giving me help i searched but unfortunately i did not find the solution i'm looking for.
I created the email function but I am blocked I do not know how to proceed later.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the resource is public so there is no need for authentication. There should be a route that retrieves the content from database and passes to the view

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/document/{id}/download", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @param int $id  file's record ID in the database
 *
 * @return BinaryFileResponse | View
 */
public function getDocumentAction(int $id)
{
    try {

        /** @var MyFileManager $fileManager */
        $fileManager = $this->get('my_file_manager');

        //The file path should be saved in the database
        $splFileObj = new \SplFileObject($fileManager->find($id)->getPath());
        $filename = $splFileObj->getFilename();

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($splFileObj);
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $filename);
        $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');

    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException | InvalidInputException $e) {

        return $this->view($e, Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Path the link of the above action as the link in the email to download the file (construct the url by id). Obviously, if the path is not public, user needs to authenticate.